# How can I import urls for background images to a css file?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a landing page with a slide show of five images from a css file. I want the urls in the css to come from an array so that I can change which images are in the slides by changing the array. Is it possible to have the background image URL come from an array?

Here is the snippet of css where I want the URLs to come from an array:

```
.slideshow li:nth-child(1) { 
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/K3mPv14.jpg) 
}
.slideshow li:nth-child(2) { 
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/SBEmFpv.jpg);
  animation-delay: 10s; 
}
.slideshow li:nth-child(3) { 
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/emvhOnb.jpg);
  animation-delay: 20s; 
}
.slideshow li:nth-child(4) { 
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/2LSMCmJ.jpg);
  animation-delay: 30s; 
}
.slideshow li:nth-child(5) { 
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/TVGe0Ef.jpg);
  animation-delay: 40s; 
}
```

Comment: You can create a PHP array and use its values in your CSS?

Comment: In my example, it would choose between file1 and file2 randomly each time the page is rendered/loaded.

Answer (score 0):

*UPDATED* ADDED A FEW MORE DETAILLED STEPS AT THE OP REQUEST*

1. Create new file called random-arrays.php in your root directory.
2. Open/edit the new php file.
3. Insert the following code, **replacing 'file1.png' and 'file2.png' with your image files**. These files should also be in the root directory.

```
<?php
  $img = array('file1.png', 'file2.png' ); // array of filenames

  $i = rand(0, count($img)-1); // generate random number size of the array
  $selectedImg = "$img[$i]"; // set variable equal to which random filename was chosen
?>
```

4. Save file and/or place in root directory of your website.
5. Open your html page and add the following line of code after the BODY opening tag ():

```
<?php require './random-arrays.php';?>
```

6. Add the following to your CSS stylesheet (or inline if it's inlined), ***replacing the name of the class with your class***.

```
.the_class_of_your_image_div {
background-image: url('<?php echo $selectedImg; ?'>
/* other css styling such as background-position, background-size, etc. */
```

Enjoy the randomness of your background image.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't learned php yet. Do you think it could be done in Java Script node?

Comment: OK, well maybe see with Joimee to troubleshoot his code, I'm not a JS expert. But if you want to implement the PHP solution, I can guide you it's very easy I used this in my very first months of coding. I'll update my answer with the few steps more in details.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to have the background image URL come from an array?

Yes, but only through javascript

```
// replace these with your images
const images = [
 'http://i.imgur.com/K3mPv14.jpg',
 'http://i.imgur.com/K3mPv14.jpg',
 'http://i.imgur.com/K3mPv14.jpg',
 'http://i.imgur.com/K3mPv14.jpg',
 'http://i.imgur.com/K3mPv14.jpg',
];

// slideshow
const slideshow = document.querySelector('.slideshow');

// adding your styles
slideshow.children.forEach((slideshowItem, index) => {
 slideshowItem.style.backgroundImage = `url(${images[index]})`;
 slideshowItem.style.animationDelay = `${10 * index}s`;
});
```

Comment: That's another way of doing things in JS, the more the merrier.

Comment: Thanks. This points me in the right direction. I tried replacing the URLs and copy and pasting your code inside of a script tag in the bottom of the header. I am getting an error saying "Cannot read property 'children' of null".

Comment: are your images in the root directory? otherwise you need to specifiy a path in the images array.

Comment: You need to check in the console if `slideshow` has a property of children. Try `console.log(slideshow)`

Comment: LaurentC- The image urls are not in the root directory. My goal is to parse 5 image urls from a reddit api json into an array, then use those urls as the background-image attribute for each <li> in the slideshow <ul>.

Comment: Joimee Cajandab- I checked the browser console for console.log(slideshow) and it said "null".

Comment: Here is the GitHub for the slider html and css: https://github.com/nax3t/background-slider 

How would you make the background-image urls come from an array?